# Scroll effect using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm very new to web design, so please bear with me if I use the wrong terminology.

Basically, I have a bunch of content that I want to keep offscreen - below the bottom of the browser window so it's not visible no matter how large the user makes the window - then allow the content to be displayed once the user scrolls down. http://demicreative.com/ does a great job of this, if you notice, no matter how large you make your browser the About Us content stays outside the view of the window until you scroll down. I'm guessing this can be achieved using jquery but I'm a bit lost at this point.

I apologize for my inability to accurately describe what I'm looking to do, but I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's a whole lot going on with that page. But the specific feature you're looking at (header/hero content fills viewport regardless of window size) is being accomplished through a window.resize event, which is something you can do through jQuery.

Basically, every time you resize your browser window, it triggers a resize 'event' and you can attach a function to that event (the function can look at the new height value of your browser window, and copy that height value over to an object on the page). What they're doing probably looks something like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  var newHeight = $(window).height();
  $('header').css('height',newHeight);
});
```

or just...

```
$(window).resize(function(){
  $('header').css('height',$(window).height());
});
```

Again, there is quite a bit more going on that page (they are using css to create paralaxing backgrounds, using a basic animation engine to check the scroll value and apply animated position values to elements, etc) but specifically what you're asking for, it would be something like that.

Comment: Not to be a dick to those guys at demicreative.com (it is a pretty fancy site), but I was able to find 4 minor bugs pretty quickly on their page.